# Adding Tooltip for Variable in IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Is there a syntax in Visual Studio 2008 so that, in C# development, if one of my colleagues hovers over a variable, the tooltip brings up more information, like my comments? It displays that it's a local int, and while running displays a value, but I was wondering if there was a way to make it display a personal description. Sorry for the newbie question, but all my research kept bringing up very different things than what I was looking for.

Comment: The name itself should be enough explanation. Do not use hungarian notation :-)

Comment: I know, and that's how I do things, but I've noticed that sometimes it's just not enough. :(

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954029/how-to-write-comments-documentation-for-variables-fields-lists-in-vs-2010). It is for VS2010, but it may work for 2008.

Comment: Oh that's perfect! I must have missed that post. Sorry about that. If you want to post an answer, I'll mark it as the good answer and you can get some rep. :)

Comment: The rep does not matter :-) I can post it as an answer so that your question doesn't go limbo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a duplicate question, with an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954029/how-to-write-comments-documentation-for-variables-fields-lists-in-vs-2010)

As I stated earlier one should use appropriate naming, and avoid using hungarian notation.

Comment: If it has a duplicate answer, you should flag it as a duplicate with the link to it.